# No content attribute for UITableView in .xib

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, interface-builder

(XCode 4.2, iOS 5)

In order to reuse a tableview (with a navigation bar and edit/add buttons) I created a `UITableViewController` subclass with it's own `.xib`. However, when I add a `UITableView` to my `.xib`'s main view the content attribute (which I want to set to dynamic prototypes) it doesn't show up. It just shows the sample content (`California: Brea, Burlingame, ...`). When I add a `UITableView` in my main storyboard the content attribute does show up.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For people trying to solve this, it is impossible to set dynamic prototypes cells in a `.xib`, or even static cells. No embedded sections or cells are supported in `.xib` files.
If you drag a Table View Controller into a `.xib`, you'll get an error:

> Table views with embedded sections and cells are only supported in
>   storyboard documents

Xcode 6.3.2