# Limit the scroll for UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a TableViewController:

[image]

As you see I have my own custom bar at the top. 
The UITable View is just a `static` one, and I add a view at the top of UITableView.

The thing is when I scroll the TableView to top-side it become like bellow image, and I don't want it. is there any easy code that I can limit the scroll for the tableView?

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

since UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView you can use this UIScrollViewDelegate method to forbid scrolling above the top border

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == self.tableView) {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I used it to synchronize two parallel table views and works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

Yo will need to set the bounce property of the uitableview to NO

```
    UITableView  *tableView;
    tableView.bounces = NO;
```

Edit: Note also you can uncheck the bounces from interface builder too

Please check this answer for further details [Disable UITableView vertical bounces when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768673/disable-uitableview-vertical-bounces-when-scrolling)

Comment: Is it any possibility to make the scroll like that just when we go bottom to top? because It is better if when we scroll top to bottom it works normally.

Comment: another possible answer is the one of Mathhias Bunch, it should cover waht you need

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and asked our UX-Designer, how it would be better to do. He said, that both strict solutions (prevent bouncing or allow it as it is) are bad. It's better to allow bouncing but only for some space

My solution was:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == self.tableView {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < -64 {
            scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: -64), size: scrollView.frame.size), animated: false)
            scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: scrollView.frame.size), animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Where `64` was that "some space" for me. Code stops tableView at `-64` from the top and brings it up with an animation.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you have set-up your custom bar as part of your tableview. Put your `custom bar` in a separate view not in the tableview and put your tableview below custom bar when you are setting up your views. You need to create your custom view controller that will have your custom bar and your static table view.

Comment: You understood right. Then I can't create a static table view in a tableViewController.

Comment: You need to create you own view controller which will contain a table view and the custom bar. If you have define a table view with some predefined contents you can link to it in storyboard

Comment: I tried it in a .xib file, and there I did not have an option to set the content of TableView to static. So it means I have to create a dynamic Table View. right?

Comment: How could you set the content of tableView to static in a .xib file?

Comment: you can go to your attributes inspector and change the contents from dynamic prototypes to static cells

Comment: I said the `.xib file`. I did not have an option to set the content to static. I think you are not right in this case.

Comment: Create a simple .xib file and then drag a UITableView in it. See the properties. Can you set the content of tableView to static? there is no option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953490/no-content-attribute-for-uitableview-in-xib

Comment: again...if you want ur content to be static u should set the content properties of your table view in interface builder to static cells and edit ur cell it is not an option on the xib.

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of Mattias's answer:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (scrollView == self.ordersTable) {
            if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
                scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create your view controller object as type `UIViewController` and not `UITableViewController`. Then add the custom bar as a subview to `self.view`. Create a separate `UITableView` and add it below the custom bar. That should make custom bar static and table view scrollable.

**Update:**

In order to make the tableview static you need to set it as

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = NO:
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yes, but then the tableView can not be static. right? I tried it in a .xib file, and there I did not have an option to set the `content` of TableView to static.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please let me know if that is what you wanted.