# UITableViewController - limit the scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, scroll, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController which contains a **View** and a **Table View Section**.

**View** contains a label that indicates the title of the table.

My problem is that the scroll includes the **View**. What I want is to keep **View** static (exclude from scrolling) and to scroll only **Table**. (I use static cells)

Thanks.

Comment: Put the view outside `UITableView`.

Comment: He can't do it in `UITableViewController`.

Comment: What he can't do it? Just don't put the view into `UITableView[Cell]` and that's it.

Comment: `UITableViewController.view` is always `UITableView` -- he can't put it outside.

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805615/limit-the-scroll-for-uitableview/12806308#12806308

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchy of a UITableViewController is

```
- UIView
-- UIScrollView
---- UITableView
```

Initially you're in the UITableView when modifying items, so you'll want to add the portion that you do not want to scroll to the UIView (outside of our scrollView).  So you'll need to call super a couple times like this:

[self.superview.superview.view addSubview:viewThatDoesNotScroll];

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what you mean. Can you please give me more details. I use static cells and when I create custom class I get "Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances". Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but that is not the view hierarchy for the UITableViewController. A UITableViewController's view property points at a UITableView record. And UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView. You should never put an UITableView object inside an UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Since `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // mySubview is an instance variable, declared in .h file
    [self.tableView addSubview:mySubview];
    // here goes the rest of your code
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if(scrollView == self.tableView) {
        mySubview.frame = CGRectMake(mySubview.frame.origin.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y, mySubview.frame.size.width, mySubview.frame.size.height);
    }
}
```

The code was taken from WWDC '10 or '11 (I don't remember), so I'm sure it's the most appropriate way to do it.

**Explanation:** In `-viewDidLoad` you create your view and add it as a subview of your tableView. You can do it in `-loadView` or `-init` - it doesn't matter. The most important lines are in the `-scrollViewDidScroll:` method. This method is called whenever user drags the scrollView, so you can simply set the `origin.y` of your subview to `contentOffset.y` of the scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Do not UITableViewController. Use UIViewController and manage the views outside of  the UITableView object. If you need, you can also implement UIViewControllerContainment to manage different views and different view controllers inside your custom view controller.